# Site wide link fade EXCLUDING one element

Tags: css

I'm extremely novice when it comes to CSS.  So forgive my probably very ignorant question.

I am working on adding a fade effect when hovering on links / menu items on my website.  I've found a piece of code that does the trick which I've listed below.  However, I am looking for a simple way to exclude this from affecting my main page content.  This code is making the transition time on a slideshow choppy and slow.  Is there a way to simply exclude this from affecting the main page content?

```
a {
-webkit-transition:all 200ms ease-in;
-o-transition:all 200ms ease-in;
}
```

Thank you!

Comment: You may want to take a look at CSS-classes.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not a web designer - I'm just creating a website for my home business using a Wordpress template.  I'm sure classes would be beneficial.

Comment: I understand. The answer given by Ash Wilson should suffice then.

Answer (score 1):

Add another CSS rule with a more specific selector that overrides it and disables the transition. For example, if the link you want to exclude has an id of "slideshow-link":

```
a {
  -webkit-transition: all 200ms ease-in;
  -o-transition: all 200ms ease-in;
}

a#slideshow-link {
  -webkit-transition: none 0ms ease;
  -o-transition: none 0ms ease;
}
```

Or to exclude all links within a `.content` div:

```
.content a {
  -webkit-transition: none 0ms ease;
  -o-transition: none 0ms ease;
}
```